# Does the 1Rx8 and 2Rx8 RAM are compatible?

Tags: memory

I have these two RAMs:

1. Samsung 8GB 2Rx8 PC4-2133P-SE0-10.
2. Samsung 8GB 1Rx8 PC4-2133P-SA0-10.

**And my PC is HP EliteBook 820 G3.**

**Can I use these two RAMs with my PC or not, why?**

and

What does it means PC4,SE0 and SA0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- PC4 = DDR4
- S = Small Outline DIMM ("SO-DIMM"), no ECC (x64 bit module data bus)
- A = Unbuffered 16-bit Small Outline DIMM (“16b-SO-DIMM”), x16 data bus (placeholder)
- E = Unbuffered DIMM ("UDIMM"), x64 primary + 8 bit ECC module data bus
- 0 = Initial release

Just for future reference - the product numbers (M47A1K43BB0-CPB and M47A1G43DB0-CPB) tell you the details of the module.

Either of those modules should be compatible with your laptop. Dual-channel RAM should be added in identical pairs, so I can't be certain whether they are compatible with each other. It's not an optimal combination, so the performance might not be as good as with identical modules, but they should work.

I'd just stick them in and test - if they aren't compatible, the system just won't boot properly. As long as you don't use excessive force when inserting them, you're not likely to break anything :-)

Sources:

- https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/global.semi/file/resource/2018/06/DDR4_Product_guide_May.18.pdf
- https://support.hp.com/hr-en/document/c04913012